# Background for a book on Fermat's Last Theorem

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry

What is the background for the book 
'Modular Forms and Fermat's Last Theorem'?
Thanks you in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Introduction to Elliptic curves and modular forms*** by Neal Koblitz.

I also like the short ***Lectures on Modular Forms*** by Joseph Lehner.  I only wish he used more figures to illustrate the book; it is rather algebra heavy when certain ideas are very graphical.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer.